# Bleeding Edge/Nightly Build dependency management in Python. Strategies and best practices?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, release-management, nightly-build

---

## The situation

---

You have 2 software products in development, a **library** which presents an API and a **GUI tool** that exposes the library for end users. **Additionally**, you expect a lot of technical staff at your place to use the library as a building block for all sorts of relevant custom code, tools and assets.

Both software products *(library and GUI tool)* are actively in development and influence each other. For both you want the most easy way of distribution and devenv setup, using **pip**:

```
pip install gui_tool
or
pip install library
```

---

### Gui Tool (use case 1)

---

The installation of the GUI tool happens via **pip** and the dependencies are noted with a hard version number within the **setup.py**. Your library is one of those dependencies:

```
...
install_requires = ['library==1.2, package_x==0.3, package_y==0.6'],
...
```

The installation procedure consists of installing the tools and resolving the dependencies into a fresh virtualenv. Because every dependency version is hardwired, you control a stable and consistent installation. Nightly builds/bleeding edge dependencies can be controlled by devs through manually updating **library** to newer versions:

```
pip install --upgrade library  # get the latest nightly build/hotfix release on your own
```

---

### Custom code/tools (use case 2)

---

As mentioned, a lot of code and custom tools might be built using the API that your **library** provides. Everybody willing to use it should install/update it through pip easily with the oneliner from the top.

---

### Problem

---

Fellow **GUI tool** developers should be able to pull in nightly builds/hotfix releases of the **library** dependency with pip. Other staff, using **library** as a building block somewhere, should always get the latest stable version using pip. You want to remain one unique release procedure for **library** providing stable versions, bleeding edge and hotfix releases through X.Y.Z versioning.

**There are a few possible solutions to this, like:**

- maintaining a **readme** for the custom users that states the stable versions they should be installing with pip
- or setting up some magic within the setup.py for the **Gui Tool** cloning the git repo and using it through **python setup.py develop** *(Versioning can then be handled by devs via checkouts in the repo)*.

---

However, none of these seem particularly elegant, so I am interested in your solutions, ideas or best practices for stable/bleeding edge/nightly build dependency management for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing a "bleeding edge" version in `pip` can be achieved by using the [`--pre` flag of `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel/?highlight=#cmdoption--pre)

From `pip install --help`:

> --pre                       Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

You should add [classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers) to your project, in particular set your stable release to `Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable` and your "bleeding edge releases" to anything below 5.

This is how major python packages manage their alphas, e.g.: the [django project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django) with currently 1.9a in alpha and 1.8.5 in stable.

To upgrade to the latest version flagged as `Development Status :: 3 - Alpha`
:

```
pip install --pre --upgrade library
```

Users using the library as building blocks need not now about the alpha releases and will go with a regular `pip install library` which will install the latest stable flagged version.

Comment: **That sounds pretty much like the way to do it!** Thanks and upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to manage on library or several libraries?

It seems like you have a case of complex Python dependency tracking and deployment. There are few large Python projects which face the same issue with the need to track several different release channels, betas and bleeding edge. Most notable them is [Plone](http://plone.org) which sports more than 300 MB of Python egg source code.

Plone used a [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) as the dependency manager instead of pip to tackle the complexity. Buildout offers mix and match configuration files for Python dependencies.

To quickly grasp how this happens see Plone core buildouts

- Example of Plone 5.0 latest: http://dist.plone.org/release/5.0-latest/versions.cfg
- Example of older Plone 4.x latest release: http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3rc1/versions.cfg
- Github repository which drives the process https://github.com/plone/buildout.coredev - however the complexity here has grown so high that it is no longer very easy for an outsider to grasp what is going on. Release process described here http://buildoutcoredev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release.html

Warning Buildout is arcane and rough on the edges like just surfaced volcano island of hot lava. Is it more elegant than generating pip requirements.txt with custom scripts? Yes if you have more than one library which needs to be managed.